# Java generics and Serializable

Tags: java, generics, serialization

We created an abstract class that we use for dealing with Redis (set/get values), that looks like follows:

```
public abstract class AbstractCachedSupport<T extends Serializable> {
    protected T get(CacheKey key, Supplier<T> supplier) {...}
    // ...
}
```

What I'm not happy about is that we cannot use interfaces like List, Map when extending this class:

```
public class CachedMap extends AbstractCachedSupport<Map<String, Integer>>
```

because they do not extend Serializable, so we have to always use concrete classes:

```
public class CachedMap extends AbstractCachedSupport<HashMap<String, Integer>>
```

Needless to say, this has its share of problems, when migrating from one concrete class to another for instance. It's also not something I would call best practice, but maybe that's just me.

An alternative that gives us the flexibility to work with interfaces would be to remove the bounded typing and check at runtime whether T extends Serializable:

```
public abstract class AbstractCachedSupport<T> {
    public AbstractCachedSupport() {
        final Class<T> type = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        if (!Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("T must extend Serializable");
        }
    }

    protected T get(CacheKey key, Supplier<T> supplier) {...}
    // ...
}
```

This leaves us without compile time checking on T extending Serializable, not a nice thing either.

Do you know of any other way how we could solve this elegantly? Would you rather use the first one (bounded type parameter) or the second (runtime checking only)?

A compromise would be to go for the first and always use a container class for holding the collection:

```
public class IntegerParamsContainer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Map<String, Integer> map;
}

public class CachedMap extends AbstractCachedSupport<IntegerParamsContainer>
```

But this has in the end the same problem as the second: there is no compile time checking, the responsibility lies on the shoulders of the developers to always use collections that implement Serializable.

**Edit:**
Some of the classes extending `AbstractCachedSupport` are Spring (version 4.1 currently) component classes and they are not called `CachedMap` or something similar, rather `CityAutocompleteDataBean`, `WrParamsDataBean` etc..
If we add generics to these component classes, we'll end up with declarations such as:

```
@Inject
private CityAutocompleteDataBean<ArrayList<String>>;
@Inject
private WrParamsDataBean<HashMap<String, WrData>>;
```

as opposed to

```
@Inject
private CityAutocompleteDataBean;
@Inject
private WrParamsDataBean;
```

The reason for using `<ArrayList<String>>` and `<HashMap<String, WrData>>` will escape most developers when they'll see such lines of code. I also find it rather ugly, considering where we started and what we use this for.

Nonetheless, this works as requested by me, thank you Jesper.

Comment: As a side note, I don't think the run-time check works, i.e. if you have a `class CachedMap extends AbstractCachedSupport<Map<String, Integer>>` you have the same problem where `T` argument isn't Serializable. What you actually need to validate are field values of each instance, not declarations. (But it should be that serialization does this already.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using the following syntax:

```
public abstract class AbstractCachedSupport<T extends Serializable> {
    // ...
}

public class CachedMap<T extends Map<String, Integer> & Serializable>
        extends AbstractCachedSupport<T> {
    // ...
}
```

This means that the type `T` must implement `Map<String, Integer>` and also `Serializable`.

Then you could use `CachedMap` with a specific `Map` implementation that implements `Serializable`:

```
CachedMap<HashMap<String, Integer>> cachedMap = new CachedMap<>();
```

Comment: You beat me, I was about to post that :)

Comment: This would require Java 8?

Comment: @bot No, this does not require Java 8.

Comment: @Jesper Great. Learnt something new today.

Comment: Some of the classes extending `AbstractCachedSupport` are Spring component classes. Would you still do it like this?

Comment: @MariusBurz Do you mean classes with Spring's `@Component` annotation? Why would that change anything? They're just classes like other classes.

Comment: Because you'd have to write `@Inject private CachedMap<HashMap<String, Integer>> bean;` instead of `@Inject private CachedMap bean;` everywhere where beans from such a class are injected. Obviously, it will work without generics as well, but it will give you ugly warnings.

Comment: You could create a `public class CachedHashMap extends CachedMap<HashMap<String, Integer>>`, and use `@Inject private CachedHashMap bean;`